# Digital ocean droplet with dokku asking for password instead using ssh public key

Tags: deployment, ssh, digital-ocean, dokku

I've created dokku droplet with setting ssh public key.
When I try to connect to my droplet this way

```
ssh root@IP.ADDRESS
```

It asking for password

I destroyed my droplet many times and created this again and again, but it still not working
I used this tutorial - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-keys-with-digitalocean-droplets

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: I fixed it. My key was named "id_rsa_derzunov" and the connection was looking for "id_rsa". I forget to configure my **~/.ssh/config** with                                             `Host YOUR.DROPLET.IP.ADDRESS
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_digitalocean_dropletname`